# Use jQuery UI Selectable to select only following elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a table with some rows and and cells. Using jQuery UI Selectable how can I customize the selection so it's only possible to select cells following each other. It shouldn't be possible to select cells vertically across rows without selecting the cells between.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `selected` callback to add a class to the selected element; The class which you will use to tie `.selectable()`.  You can then use the [next siblings selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/) in combination with this, and you should be able to accomplish what you need.

To start off, you're going to want something like the following:

```
<ol>
    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
</ol>
```

Then, as you select one, which will fire the callback, you want to make the second selectable.

```
<ol>
    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee ui-selected">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
</ol>
```

And so on.

Comment: Thanks, would be awesome if you could show some simple example?

Comment: What would you like an example of, specifically?

Comment: How I can use the `selected` callback to do what I'd like to do. Seems like that callback is used when the elements are already selected..